# Array with method that sets itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an array object that can set itself.
Something like this...

```
array = new Array(10)
array.someMethod = function () {
    this = new Array(20)
}
```

Except *this* doesn't work because `this` can't be set like that.

More or less I want an object that I use `array[index]` on.

Comment: Why? Just mutate the array?! Whats the usecase for this?

Comment: I am not sur what you're asking , are you looking to generate an array with a specific length ?

Comment: Seems a bit vague. Please elaborate.

Comment: What you're asking either makes no sense or is completely unclear.

Comment: Even though you *could* do this, you shouldn't - arrays shouldn't have developer-set properties other than its numeric indicies. If you want to set other properties, you should use an object instead.

Comment: "More or less I want an object that I use array[index] on." ??? explain more.

Comment: The current answer by nvioli is what I did while waiting for some responses. What I wanted though was to add a method to an array that just filled it with random values after setting it to a given length, but it really doesn't need to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me this could be accomplished by using an object and storing the array in one of the object's properties. I'm learning about the `class` syntax, so I did it that way, but I think the same approach would work with regular objects.

```js
class MyArray {
  constructor(num) {
    console.log(`building MyArray with ${num} objects`);
    this.innerArray = new Array(num);
  }
  
  update(num) {
    console.log(`updating MyArray to have ${num} objects`);
    this.innerArray = new Array(num);
  }

  get() { return this.innerArray }
}

let foo = new MyArray(10);
foo.get()[0] = "bar";
console.log(foo.get());
foo.update(20);
foo.get()[0] = "baz";
console.log(foo.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you asked your question is not quite right you should explain better.
not sure this is what you want.

you can't change the `this` in javascript.
but function in `prototype` will be called with the object as their context. so Array.prototype.length gives the length in `arr.length` by having arr as it's context. [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

so

```js
Array.prototype.testA = function() {
  // this.splice(0,this.length);
  var a = [3,5,7];
  // new Array(23).fill().map( (a,_)=>_)
  this.splice(0,this.length,...a);
}

Array.prototype.testAA = function() {
  var a = [3,5,7];
  this.splice(this.length,0,...a);
}

var a = [1];
a.testAA();
console.log(a);
a.testA();
console.log(a);
```